# What is the difference between 'as' and 'while'?

Tags: meaning

> **As** the owls flooded into the Great Hall as usual, everyone's attention
>   was caught at once by a long, thin package carried by six large
>   screech owls.
>
> A thousand live bats fluttered from the walls and ceiling **while** a
>   thousand more swooped over the tables in low black clouds, making the
>   candles in the pumpkins stutter. (Harry Potter book1)

In the examples, what’s the difference between ‘as’ and ‘while’? 
Can each be changed with each other?

Comment: In these two contexts there's no difference in meaning, and they can reasonably be swapped. I think there's actually a good argument for doing so in the first example, to avoid the slightly jarring clash with *"**as** usual"*, where *"as"* performs a different function.

Comment: I agree. The only thing to add is that _as_ can have causative as well as temporal meaning, so that in some contexts care needs to be taken in its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a slight connotative difference, in addition to the causative meaning of "as".

- The word "while" implies that there are two comparable events taking place (in terms of duration) — there are a thousand bats fluttering and a thousand bats swooping over the same length of time.
- The word "as" often refers to a specific temporal instance occurring within the confines of a larger duration of time — the owls flew in the room over a length of time, but everyone's attention was caught at once.

Generally speaking, they are interchangeable, but the reader will get a slightly different idea of when the events took place in comparison to each other.